# Combine duplicate cells in another column

Tags: excel

How to achieve these output from the Data automatically?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may have already guessed from the heading of this section, distinct values in Excel are all different values in a list, i.e. unique values and first instances of duplicate values. For example:

```
A     |B
-------------------
A     |A
A     |B
B     |
B     |
```

To get a distinct list in Excel, use the following formulas.

Array distinct formula (requires pressing Ctrl + Shift + Enter):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$10, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$1:B1, $A$2:$A$10), 0)), "")
```

Regular distinct formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$10, MATCH(0, INDEX(COUNTIF($B$1:B1, $A$2:$A$10), 0, 0), 0)), "")
```

Where:

A2:A10 is the source list.
B1 is the cell above the first cell of the distinct list. In this example, the distinct list begins in cell B2 (it's the first cell where you enter the formula), so you reference B1.

Comment: Thanks, What do you mean by columns position?

Comment: columns position is like E2, A3

Comment: Could you please check the image now and tell me exact formula?

Comment: B is your output and must have the formula see https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/04/21/get-list-unique-values-excel/

Comment: i suggest to user a database for this

Answer (score 0):

Select and Copy in a different column your values, go under the tab "Data", under "Data Tools", you will find there "Remove duplicates", you click it and select only the data you would like to find the unique values with, thus you choose whether the current and only columns are sufficient or if you want to find unique values taking into account also adjacent columns.